# Node web server crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm working on Node + Mongo + Express to create REST API. There are cases when node server gets crashed and I've to restart it again. I'm using forever to do the restart stuff. But I am unable to find the solution for process which are lost during the crash.

Example: I am handling 10 http request at a moment and my node server get crashed for any request. In this case other 9 running request will be lost.

Is there any fallback mechanism to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I see right now would be a NodeJS cluster, which I believe the master will handle the crash of one of his child and move the http request, but, if this does not work then make it with nginx and some node processes at the same time, it will handle that kind of things

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I agree with your point, but the real problem is to save other running process on same node.
We can redirect other(new) requests if a node server is down, but what about the running requests?

Answer (score 0):

The server crashes if there is an unhandled exception, so you need to add error handling to your functions with `try` `catch`. There are several events sent to the process objects that can help you with your problem. You could try listening for [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) and then follow a strategy like it's mentioned here: http://blog.argteam.com/coding/hardening-node-js-for-production-part-3-zero-downtime-deployments-with-nginx/, just replace 'SIGTERM'.